# Symfony2, How to cast data type in a twig file?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have some scenario like below :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RolesFeatures", mappedBy="role", cascade={"all"})
     **/
    private $rolesFeatures;
}
```

In my index file I would like to get them:

```
{{ role.rolesFeatures.getId() }}
```

I get this :

```
 An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal
 Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string
 in C:\wamp\www\PMI_sf2\app\cache\dev\twig\63\81\679fca1c2da64d0ebbcd5661bc6d.php line 99")
 in PMIHomePagesBundle:HomePages:mainHome.html.twig at line 49.
```

How I can Cast Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to it real object class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rolesFeatures is an array so you need to iterate over it.  Something like:

```
{% for roleFeature in role.rolesFeatures %}
    {{ roleFeature.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get this error : Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::serialize() must return a string or NULL

Comment: @PMoubed Does it matched for you? because I have a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175708/query-a-manytomany-relation-and-display-the-good-result-in-symfony-with-doctrine). Thank you to help if you can.